# "urlmon.h" doesn't exist. Cannot find any solutions other than some posts from 2004

Tags: c++, urlmon

I am using an open sourced script from github which contains the following lines at the top:

```
#include <urlmon.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")
```

However, when I try to build it, it shows the following error:

`fatal error: urlmon.h: No such file or directory`

I have looked around for hours upon hours but there are no solutions I can find.

Comment: Urlmon is part of the Microsoft Win32 API. Do you have a Windows SDK installed for your compiler?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am not quite sure. Please can you guide me on how I can do this?

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: Have a [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/) to use

Answer (score 2):

This header contains functions used by the Microsoft Component Object Model (COM) and the Windows Shell.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/urlmon/

You need to setup your environment for Win32 development

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/desktop-programming

Comment: How can I fix this error then?

Comment: @Axqua if you follow the link you see it's part of the Win32 API. Two more clicks and you reach this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/desktop-programming

Comment: @bolov I understand that this is related. However, I don't know how to exactly fix the problem.

Comment: @Axqua you set up Win32 as described on the page

Comment: @Jellyboy Urlmon **uses** COM, it is not **part of** COM. Two different technologies.

Comment: @Axqua Can I guess that you cloned this repo on Linux? This library is likely Windows only.

Comment: @Jellyboy Incorrect. I am currently on Windows 10 and very confused why this problem is occuring.

Comment: @Axqua because either you don't have an environment setup for Windows development, or it is outdated. We don't know, because you haven't provided any details about it yet.

Comment: @Axqua Check if you have your environment setup: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/desktop-programming